# How to get values from a Map with different value types? (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, types

I have a utility function that returns `Map<String, Object>`, but that Map always has this structure:

```
{ "a": <something of type1>, "b": <something of type2> }
```

In outer function, where I call this utility function, I want to get the value associated with key `a`. I'm trying to do something such as:

```
Map<String, Object> data = findData(input); // findData is the utility function
Type1 type1obj = data.get("a"); // error here
```

But then I get the Incompatible Types error:

```
Required: com.blah.blah.Type1
Found: java.lang.Object
```

How am I supposed to grab the value associated with key `a`? FYI: I'm VERY new to Java.

Comment: The usual answer is that you're *not* supposed to do that, but supposed to do something type-safe instead. What's this "utility function", and why does it return `Map<String,Object>`, particularly instead of a class with properties `a` and `b`?

Comment: Please, consider to change your logic in your code. Just ask yourself: "what does it mean when I have a String as a key and *any* Object associated with that key?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the Object retrieved from Map to the type you required:

```
Type1 type1obj = (Type1) data.get("a");
```

But with the code above you have to make sure the type of value associated with key "a" is Type1, otherwise a `ClassCastException` will thrown at runtime.

If you cannot guarantee the type of the Object retrieved, you can check it like:

```
Object obj = data.get("a");
Type1 type1obj;
if(obj instanceof Type1) {
    type1obj = (Type1) obj;
} else {
    //to print error log or do some workaround
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for casting?

Comment: There are differences between compilation time and runtime. The map is declared as `Map<String, Object>`, so everything retrieved from this map will be treated as `Object` at compilation time. You could be absolutely sure that the runtime type of the `Object` retrieved is `Type1`, but the compiler cannot, so you have to cast it to the corresponding type in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, because your map has `Object` as its value type, you need to cast, but you can hide this with a *typed* utility method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T get(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    return (T)map.get(key);
}
```

So then due to java's *type inference* this will compile:

```
Type1 type1obj = get(data, "a");
```

Adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` stops your IDE/compiler complaining about an "unsafe cast".

Comment: I can see what you are saying (since the OP mentioned there are only two possible types), but this will result in a `ClassCastException` when someone does `IncompatibleType typeObj = get(data, "a")` and there is no way a compiler can catch it.

Comment: @user7 I do this often. The trick is lots of testing. There should never be a ClassCastException if you have lots of functional tests.

Answer (score 0):

Basically whenever I reach this point of storing with a HashMap or any map for that sort. I tend to go ahead and cast it. Take for example I have a class named Module that I am getting the value of and the key is the module name. I would go 
(Module) map.get(modName);